# Ionic Keyboard not showing Accessory Bar

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, keyboard

I'm using the ionic framework for the first time to develop a hybrid app (version is up to date). Upon testing my current work with the provided DevApp, I cannot get the accessory bar to show above my iPhone keyboard by any means. I tried to install the https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/, added it to my modules and in app.components.ts my constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, keyboard : Keyboard) {
platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
  keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
});
}
```

There are no errors in the console, only the bar is not appearing. Is it only because of the DevApp, or am I doing another mistake?

If more information is required, I will be glad to provide it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi rufrage, for show the keyboard accesory bar need comment the line where is keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false); .This will do that your forms in iOS and Android have a button to go to the next input or submit the form.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t work. In fact, I entered this line exactly because the buttons don’t show by default, so I‘m setting „hide“ to false with this command. I can’t tell, however, if this is only in the development app, or if everything works correct in deployment.

Comment: in the ionic serve dont show the accesory bar. This is only for physical devices

Comment: Thank you, I can now close my question